# How would I save form field values when switching to another form partial dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a page called `/index` and you can add a `House` and `Dog`. The page starts out blank but has links on the side that you can click to dynamically bring up one of the forms. These forms are in their own partials.

I will use the Dog model for this question/example. A `Dog` belongs to a `House`.

```
class Dog
 attr_accessible :name, :primary_color, :secondary_color, :house_id......... 
 belongs_to :house
end
```

DogsController

```
def new
 @dog = Dog.new

 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
 end
end
```

dogs/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@dog, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => "shared/error_message", :locals => { :f => f } %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :primary_color %>
    <%= f.input :secondary_color %>
    <%= f.association :house, :prompt => "Select a House" %>      
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Done' %>
<% end %>
```

PagesController

```
def index

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

pages/index.html.erb

```
<li><%= link_to "Dog", new_dog_path, :remote => true %></li>

<div id="generate-form">
</div>
```

dogs/new.js.erb

```
$("#generate-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'dogs/form', locals: { dog: @dog })) %>");
```

Now sometimes though, You might be in the middle of adding a Dog but need to add the House its located at before you can continue. Right now it just erases the entire Dog form if you do that. How would I save the progress of those fields when switching to the other form?  What about when a user exits the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one of many ways to do this, here's mine.

First I would remove the call to load a partial from your jQuery. That's where your problem is. Because each time the form is loaded, it writes a new version of the form.

Instead I would load both of them in the html itself independent of a jQuery call. And then allow the jQuery call to just toggle a hide/show. Like so :

```
<div class="dog-form">
  <%= render(:partial => 'dogs/form', locals: { dog: @dog }) %>
</div>
<div class="house-form">
  <%= render(:partial => 'house/form', locals: { house: @house }) %>
</div>
```

Then, you jQuery can look like this :

```
$("#toggle-dog-form").click(function(){ $(".dog-form").toggle() };
$("#toggle-house-form").click(function(){ $(".house-form").toggle() };
```

**Update**

If you seriously need to make sure that those forms are loaded fresh in that call for some outside reason I havn't heard of. Then you could put a conditional into the original jQuery call that sees is any of those input fields have been populated yet.

Comment: This is a great idea, but what about if I plan on having over 20 models, Dog and House just being the starting point? Wouldn't this slow down the page tremendously?

Comment: Not really. It's just text. Unless there's some crazy images loading. Compare that to having to wait on an AJAX load to come back. -- Ok so alternatively.. one could..load each form via AJAX, and any variables that they have added thus so far, can be stashed in a hidden div `rel` attribute, when a user clicks to load another form. the Jquery can handle what the div id is, and its value as a hash pair. Then when a form is loaded, a call is sent out to the hidden div to see if a hash pair exists for that form, and pre-populates it.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll switch up my design to this way and see how it turns out. Thank you.